# Vector by Vector division

Tags: linear-algebra

I found quite some questions on Vector by Vector division and most of them focused on the fact that there are different Vector-Vector products and for the cross product the division would not make sense.

But what about Vector-Vector division as an inverse to Vector-Scalar multiplication?

What are the problems of defining the partial function $\div : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
  a \div b =
  \begin{cases}
    s &\text{ such that } s b = a \\
    undefined &\text{ if no such $s$ exists}
  \end{cases}
$$

And (assuming there were no problems with that definition), how unexpected would it be to find such a definition in the wild?

---

As some people have asked about the motivation for this:
The motivation comes from a C++ codebase, so not super mathy. We want to see if a Ray $\langle start, dir \rangle$ hits a Point $p$ and a simple implementation for this is to check if there exists a scalar $s$ such that $p = start + s \cdot dir$. While thinking about the name for the operation that finds this $s$, we thought about just using the division operator. So the question for us is "is $\div$ a good name for this operation?"

Comment: What is the motivation? To make a definition you must first make sure there is a clear concept you want to capture, that is either interesting/beautiful/useful/commonly occurring

Comment: If you have a use case for "vector vector" division then sure, make a definition, but I challenge you to motivate it

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from making a definition like that, but it doesn't seem very useful since it's only defined in the very special case where one vector is a multiple of another—in other words, it's only defined within one-dimensional subspaces, so you're not really generalizing to higher dimensions at all.

Comment: The motivation is just "is division a good name for this operation?". I've added some more detail in the question

Comment: I believe you mean $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\rightharpoonup \mathbb R$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog To me, this is exactly the same. Since I use types and not sets, I simply prefer to write the typed curried

Comment: probably just `scalarQuotient` would be reasonable

Comment: Calling this division, and especially overloading the division operator for it, sounds like it'll lead to trouble. Also you say undefined, but a function has to return *something*. If the vectors are incomparable, what does it return? NaN?

Comment: @GregMartin yes, that is the full name I prefer for it too. The division symbol is more of an extra shorthand and I want to see if it is mathematically sensible.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I can see it leading to trouble. So I wanted to check if it at least makes sense for mathematicians to call this symbol "division". For the C++ type: it returns an `optional<double>`.

Comment: How do you find if $s$ exists? Do you divide $a_i/b_i$ for the first non-zero $b_i$, and check that $a = (a_i/b_i)b$?  Also, do you use a tolerance, to address floating point errors?  I wonder how such an approach would compare to checking that:$$\frac{a \cdot b}{|a| |b|} = \pm 1$$

Comment: @Joe It is something along the lines of computing all $s_i = a_i / b_i$ and seeing if they are approximately equal. But I guess this gets out of bounds of comments and further discussions should be moved to a chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a definition like this is fine. Calling it division is a bit unusual: if I were going to talk about this out loud, I'd call this a "$\mathbf b$-to-$\mathbf a$ scaling factor".

In mathematical writing, I wouldn't want to completely identify it with division, because it messes with established expectations. Vectors appear reasonably frequently in quotients: for example, take the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) $$(A + \mathbf u \mathbf v^{\mathsf T})^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}\mathbf u \mathbf v^{\mathsf T}\!A^{-1}}{1 + \mathbf v^{\mathsf T}\!A^{-1}\mathbf u}.$$ What always happens in such cases is that the denominator simplifies to a scalar, and division by a scalar is fine.

With vector-by-vector division, there's a small chance of confusion about what operation is happening, but that's honestly unlikely. But once the denominator *could* be a vector, this takes away lots of context clues about what's going on, and makes expressions harder to interpret even if they're technically unambiguous.

The most likely way I'd talk about the expression you want to call $\mathbf a \div\mathbf b$ is as follows. Rather than say "We define the very important quantity $x = e^{\mathbf a \div\mathbf b}$, when this is defined" I would say "When $\mathbf a = \lambda \mathbf b$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, we define the very important quantity $x = e^{\lambda}$". Or whatever. Second best is writing something that makes it clear it's my own definition: writing it as $\textrm{div}(\mathbf a, \mathbf b)$, for example.

---

So what does that add up to for the C++ codebase? I don't recommend overloading the `/` operator, and personally I'd call it something like `scalingFactor` but many names could work.